# Membership.Provider And Asp.NET MVC2: Do I Really Need it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, domain-driven-design, membership-provider

I see a lot of articles and posts on *how* to create a custom MembershipProvider, but haven't found any explanation as to *why* I must/should use it in my MVC2 web app. Apart from "Hey, security is hard!", what are critical parts of the whole MembershipProvider subsystem that I should know about that I don't, because I've only read about how to override parts of it? Is there some "behind the scenes magic" that I don't see and will have to implement myself? Is there some attribute or other piece of functionality that will trip over itself without a properly setup MembershipProvider?

I am building a web app, using a DDD approach, so the way I see it, I have a User entity and a Group entity. I don't need to customize ValidateUser() under the provider; I can just have it as a method on my User entity. I have to have a User object anyways, to implement things not under the MemebrshipProvider?

So, what gives? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need it.  I have sites that use it and sites that don't.  One reason to use it is that plumbing is already there for it in ASP.NET and you can easily implement authentication by simply providing the proper configuration items (and setting up the DB or AD or whatever).

A RoleProvider, on the other hand, comes in very handy when using the built-in AuthorizeAttributes and derivatives.  Implementing a RoleProvider will save you a fair amount of custom programming on the authorization side.

Comment: In my opinion implementing some sort role provider is not that difficult. What I use now is less than 50 lines of code including custom authorization attribute.

Comment: @Necros - I didn't say it was hard, just that it's already hooked into the AuthorizeAttribute.  Maybe what you're objecting to is the chararacterization of it as a "fair amount".  To me, having to implement your own attribute when you could just use the existing one with a suitable role provider implementation qualifies.

Comment: I ended up not using it in this particular instance, but mimicking it closely.